# Could You Send Rotate Text To The Print Preview

Tags: api, winapi, printing

Developers

(StartDocPrinter WinAPI call fails in VBA)

I Saw The Above Title .... My Question is Can Send Rotate Text To Print Preview Instead Of Printer

Comment: But I m Working In Access And Not Able To Rotate Text And Show In PrintPreview ... This Is True In Print Event Of Report ' s Detail : Me.Print TextOutA Getdc(me

Comment: But I m Working In Access And Not Able To Rotate Text And Show In PrintPreview ... This Is True?  In Print Event Of Report ' s Detail : Me.Print TextOutA Getdc(me.hwnd)," Rotate 180 DEG ",16

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's your actual problem is with `StartDocPrinter` Fail, since we got few error message about it. 
But reply your question, Rotate Text can be sent to Print Preview.

Before you add Rotate Text, you need to rotate the coordinate system and draw text to context(There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955362/rotate-text-for-printing) about how to add a Rotate Text), then the Rotate Text is included in Handle of Device Context, Print Preview can get Rotate Text from this Handle of Device Context.